AG Grid Community and Tanstack Query Pagination
I've been struggling with this for a bit now as it now seems like AG Grid API reference doesn't have anything for me in this regard but generally speaking if an API Endpoint is formatted like so -
{
    "count": 1841,
    "page": 1,
    "page_size": 32,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "name": "Jerde-Abshire",
            "legal_structure": null,
            "company_type": "MANAGEMENT",
            "inception_date": null,
            "wind_up_date": null,
            "description": "",
            "logo": null,
            "team_size_front_office": 0,
            "team_size_back_office": 0,
            "isin": null,
            "sec_file_number": null,
            "cik": null,
            ...
        }
    ]
}

How would one use the page, page_size and count for pagination with AG Grid Community? It doesn;t seem like there's a real out of the box solutions with all their Examples using huge JSON exports to present paginated data.
Initially tried infinity scroll but tbh it's not suitable for our needs. Auto page size is nice but there doesn;t seem to be any AG Grid API to pass a row count to to calculate pagination numbers and now I'm left wondering how just standard pagination works with remote API endpoints
